# Advanced MySQL query, select, count, insert or update

Tags: mysql

So, I have a query, what it needs to do is;

- Check if a Token exist in the sessions table
- If not insert a token in the table
- Else update the token in the table

---

```
SELECT COUNT(token) AS founds FROM sessions WHERE token = '" . $_SESSION['prevToken'] . "'
CASE WHEN founds == 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO sessions(token, cookie, expire)
    VALUES('" . $token . "', '', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
ELSE 
    UPDATE sessions SET token = '" . $token . "', expire = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    WHERE  token = '" . $_SESSION['prevToken'] . "'
END CASE
```

But I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN founds == 0 THEN INSE' at line 2
```

And I don`t know whats wrong? The CASE syntax should be right but it isn't?

Comment: Umm.. Just an opinion, if you like to have a higher chance getting an answer, you should construct your question in a nice way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CASE WHEN..` as if it were a control structure. It isn't. It's used in queries. Apart from that, you can't use control structures like `if` or `while` in a query, those are only allowed in stored procedures or functions.

Also you have no delimiter after your `select` query.

Clément Malet's answer is right, that `==` is not used in MySQL.

Best solution would be indeed to use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) like in LHristov's answer.

Apart from that, just for completeness, here's how a correct stored procedure would look like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_or_update(IN p_prev_token varchar(255), IN p_token varchar(255))
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE token = p_prev_token ) THEN
    UPDATE sessions SET token = p_token, expire = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    WHERE  token = p_prev_token;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO sessions(token, cookie, expire)
    VALUES(p_token, '', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR));
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You would then call it with something like this (I'm no PHP programmer, therefore I don't know how to escape the variables or whatever):

```
CALL insert_or_update($_SESSION['prevToken'], $token);
```

P.S.: And in general don't `COUNT()` when all you need to know is, if there's an entry. `EXISTS()` stops as soon as the first entry is found, whereas `COUNT()` continues to scan the table.

Answer (score 0):

So you need `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Get some info from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: No, I need to update where token = '".$_SESSON['prevToken']."' not on duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '==' in MySQL.

Replace `WHEN founds == 0` with `WHEN founds = 0`

Comment: Now I get `ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN founds = 0 THEN INSER' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

you also can use

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

and not use case. ex:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```